# Type error Problem of 'Series(data frame) to str'

Tags: python

I followed a code from Kaggle as in the picture.
It changed Series to str. However, when I tried in my notebook, there is TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I don't know what is the matter.

```
train_set.head(9)

text = train_set.Review
text

print(type(text))

text_combined = str(text)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) don't post code or data as images. it can't be searched, read by screen readers, or copy/pasted. 2) what do you see with `print(str)`? I suspect you overwrote the built-in function and assigned a variable to it

Comment: When I type `print(str)`, I can see `The Capstone project has been getting delayed since JanDont expect yourself to complete the specialization.`
I don't understand the reason...ㅜㅜ

Comment: You probably overwrote str with one of your variables above. check whether you are assigning anything to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you commented, you overwrote your `str` function with a variable containing `The Capstone project has been getting delayed since JanDont expect yourself to complete the specialization`.
Change the assignment to that variable to some other variable name, and restart your kaggle kernet.